# Docker compose and concurrent integration testing

Tags: docker, jenkins, concurrency, parallel-processing, docker-compose

**Edit:** sorry, I was mistaken about the first part of this question.

<s>So I have a `docker-compose.yaml` that's working fine when ran synchronously:</s>

```
server:
  build: .
  dockerfile: "./docker/integration_tests/server/Dockerfile"
  links:
    - mongo
  environment:
    - "MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017/company"

mongo:
  image: 'mongo:3.2.6'
  ports:
    - "27017"
```

When launched with this command: `docker-compose build && docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit`

However when I launch two or three jobs to test if it works in parallel (this is in Jenkins using pipelines, so they have different directories) I'm seeing this on job A:

```
Successfully built 7b23b3a7b823
+ docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit
Creating companyservercicd3_mongo_1

ERROR: for mongo  Cannot start service mongo: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint companyservercicd3_mongo_1 (422826f73ce76526e4072f72a2b44467f9080e79a24d37d1fe2bba903854a698): Bind for 0.0.0.0:27017 failed: port is already allocated
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

And this on job B:

```
Successfully built 80aa795867eb
+ docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit
Creating companyservercicd4_mongo_1

ERROR: for mongo  Cannot start service mongo: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint companyservercicd4_mongo_1 (1591f2847e6c0d81f2c530874201ea912fa59ea35bfa27e5b25d7843e06da6b5): Bind for 0.0.0.0:27017 failed: port is already allocated
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

The docs say this about the `ports` config option:

> Expose ports. Either specify both ports (HOST:CONTAINER), or just the
>   container port (a random host port will be chosen).

I must be misunderstanding something because I thought `27017` would be within a container, and that each job would have its own container. What am I doing wrong here?

Another somewhat related question - this works well in Jenkins because Jenkins is creating a new directory per job so there are no name conflicts, but would there be a way to make this bulletproof by passing in an option that would let each run have its own name? Another user recommended doing this as a workaround:

```
`docker-compose run --rm --no-deps --name `uuidgen` ...`
```

But that would require me to rework my docker-compose.yml and convert the `up` command into the equivalent `build/create/start/attach`

Answer (score 0):

So I guess this was a false alarm - having one number for each list item under `ports` did fix the port conflicts I was experiencing.

I fixed the names not being unique enough (and therefore not as resilient to concurrency) by invoking `docker-compose build` and `up` like so: `COMPOSE_ID=`uuidgen`_; docker-compose -p $COMPOSE_ID build && docker-compose -p $COMPOSE_ID up --abort-on-container-exit`, with the command that actually runs the test living in my `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your answer, are you saying the shown compose file isn't the one you were running in jenkins? Also, you can set `$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` and do away with `-p $COMPOSE_ID`. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/

Comment: yeah I guess that's what happened, probably wasn't tracking the error and config I used as diligently as I could have. I can edit the first part out since it's irrelevant and leave the second since it might be useful. +1 on setting the project name, didn't notice that.